# In vim: cursor is a plus sign

Tags: vim

I have a weird problem on vim. When I launch it the cursor shows as a '+' sign and some operations don't work as I expect them.

Does anyone know how to get back to the "regular" mode?

Comment: Did you try pressing Esc ?

Comment: Yes. I actually just solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had `set mouse=a` in my .vimrc. Should be `set mouse=r`.